# Exceljs not load static file

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, exceljs

I have a need to generate the received data in excel, however I am facing the problem of accessing a static file on my server

I use NuxtJS + VUE a static Excel file is located in my /static folder

```
/static/Excel.xlsx
/static/Word.docx
```

If I try to access via FileReader () then I get the error

```
  var workBook = new Excel.Workbook();
  workBook.xlsx.readFile("/Excel.xlsx").then(function() {
    const ws = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
    cell = ws.getCell("A1").value;
    console.log(cell);
  });
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'F_OK' of undefined
```

This error, as I understood from the discussions, is related to browser security.
I would not want to violate the security of the browser and the application to access the file.

The option according to which the user loads the template himself is a little inconvenient, you have to do a lot of unnecessary actions

[Link to solution on https://github.com/](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/832#issuecomment-495455990)

at the same time I found a solution for Word using package: docxtemplater - it uses JSZipUtils
and the example with Word works fine, however the module for xlsx is very expensive for me

```
loadFile(url, callback) {
  JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, callback);
},

this.loadFile("/Word.docx", function(error, content) {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
      var zip = new JSZip(content);
      var doc = new Docxtemplater();
      doc.loadZip(zip);
      //... getting data from the database and inserting it into the Word template
    });
```

Is it possible to somehow use the JSZipUtils package to implement access to Excel? or have
another way is it different to get an instance of a static file without violating security?

Comment: So `/static/Excel.xlsx` is a file on the server? Is it accessible by URL? I think the first issue is that you're trying to access a server-side file from the browser.

Comment: Next you'll have to make sure it's binary data in a buffer...

Comment: if you use the URL, the error is the same: dev mode: check it now, workbook.xlsx.readFile("http://localhost:3000/Excel.xlsx"); Result Cannot read property 'F_OK' of undefined